# Make icons change from light to dark when scroll over different background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The icons need to change from light to dark, pixel by pixel, so if the page is scrolled over one icon, half is dark half is white.

My original thought was to have two icons layered on top of each other.. light could be `z-index: 0` the page `z-index: 1` and the black `z-index: 2`, however the black would always be showing.. perhaps overflow hidden on the page? But these need to be position fixed to the side of the window and fixed doesn't respect overflow.

The black portion of the page is an image, so don't rely on it being black.

[Here's a little fiddle I've made to help.](https://jsfiddle.net/wyt9ws5t/)

[image: Example image]

```css
body { width: 350px; background-color: #efefef;}
.icons { position: fixed; top: 10px; left: 10px;}
.icons .icon { color: #fff;}
.content { padding: 0 20px; background-color: #fff;}
```

```html
<div class="icons">
    <div class="icon">+</div>
    <div class="icon">+</div>
    <div class="icon">+</div>
</div>
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
<div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reprehenderit sapiente expedita voluptas provident vitae molestias ex doloribus tenetur eos at quia molestiae, aliquam cupiditate accusantium consectetur enim natus laudantium?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reprehenderit sapiente expedita voluptas provident vitae molestias ex doloribus tenetur eos at quia molestiae, aliquam cupiditate accusantium consectetur enim natus laudantium?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reprehenderit sapiente expedita voluptas provident vitae molestias ex doloribus tenetur eos at quia molestiae, aliquam cupiditate accusantium consectetur enim natus laudantium?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reprehenderit sapiente expedita voluptas provident vitae molestias ex doloribus tenetur eos at quia molestiae, aliquam cupiditate accusantium consectetur enim natus laudantium?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reprehenderit sapiente expedita voluptas provident vitae molestias ex doloribus tenetur eos at quia molestiae, aliquam cupiditate accusantium consectetur enim natus laudantium?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reprehenderit sapiente expedita voluptas provident vitae molestias ex doloribus tenetur eos at quia molestiae, aliquam cupiditate accusantium consectetur enim natus laudantium?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reprehenderit sapiente expedita voluptas provident vitae molestias ex doloribus tenetur eos at quia molestiae, aliquam cupiditate accusantium consectetur enim natus laudantium?
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have some example code?

Comment: @Terry I've added a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/0b53d42g/

Comment: Here is an interesting fiddle that I've made: https://jsfiddle.net/wyt9ws5t/1/ -- Not perfect, but it's an idea